# Can't break out of CRTP cyclical reference

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I'm trying to structure my program by using CRTP for certain parts to get rid of virtual function call overhead but I'm having trouble with cyclical references between classes.

The program basically has 2 major modes: Hello1 and Hello2 encapsulate this.  I'm wondering if perhaps I should just make an enum class Hello { Hello1, Hello2 }; and use that to template everything EXCEPT for the Deriv template type where I need to use concrete classes?  I tried searching for this but couldn't seem to find something matching my particular use case (or at least I didn't recognize).

```
template<typename T>
struct Processor
{
    std::vector<T> v_; // holds HelloContainers

    void usage1()
    {
        for (auto& v : v_)
            v->doSomethingToHello();
    }

    void specialize() { /* ... */ }
};

template<> Container<Hello1>::specialize()
{
    // something special for Hello1 only!
}


template<typename Deriv2>
struct HelloContainerBase
{
    void needsAccessFromHello1And2();

    // a whole bunch of other things that Hello{1,2} need access to
    // ..
};

template<typename T>
struct HelloContainer : public HelloContainerBase<HelloContainer<T>>
{
    void doSomethingToHello() { hello_->func2(); }
    void callFunc1() { hello_->func1(); } // <--- slow?

    void needsAccessFromHello()
    T* hello_; // needs
};


struct HelloBase
{
    virtual void func1() = 0;
};

template<typename Deriv>
struct HelloCRTP : public HelloBase
{
    void func2()
    {
        static_cast<Deriv>(this)->func2impl();
    }

    HelloContainer<Deriv>* proc_;
};

struct Hello1 : public HelloCRTP<Hello1>
{
    void func1(); // hopefully no virtual method overhead?
    void func2impl(); // no virtual method overhead

    // ...
};

struct Hello2 : public HelloCRTP<Hello1>
{
    void func1(); // hopefully no virtual method overhead?
    void func2impl(); // no virtual method overhead

    // ...
};

int main()
{

    auto hc1 = new HelloContainer<Hello1>();
    auto proc = new Processor<Hello1>
    proc.v_.push_back(hc1);

    proc.usage();
    proc.specialize();

    hc1->doSomethingToHello();

}
```

Comment: Once fixed your *"typos"*, following compile [Demo](https://ideone.com/JlJtqv).

Comment: @Jarod42 I added some calls in main that cause it to fail.  Also I'm asking about ways to improve this code as it seems a bit hectic!

Comment: Where is your `Container<>` template? Is this code really minimal to ask your question?

Comment: Fix your code to show exact error you got. With trivial fixes, it works [here](https://ideone.com/exGark)...